# How to query for a list of results using geocoder API from Google?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geocoding, google-geocoder

so I'm using the built in `geocoder.geocode` function for google maps and implementing it like so:

```
   geocoder.geocode({ address: place }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            const cityLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
            const cityLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
            setMapMarkers([...mapMarkers, cityInformation])
            // other logic here that loads it on to the map
        } else {
            alert('Place not recognized, please try searching again')
        }
    })
```

this all works fine. however, during some testing I noticed a bug. I searched for `Split` in Croatia but it added `Split` in California to my map. This got me thinking if there is a way for it to return a list of results for all `Split`s in this case, so the user can then select the chosen one and then I add it to the map. is it possible for this function to cater to that? or is there more logic I need to add?

Comment: I think you didn't search for *Split in Croatia* as you mentioned. You searched for *Split* alone, which is ambiguous. You should either search for `Split, Croatia` or `Split, HR` for example, which will trigger the appropriate result. We don't know your use case, but if `Split` must be entered by a user, you're better using the Places Autocomplete as explained in the answer you received (you can get the coords from the service, no need to geocode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that this code:

```
geocoder.geocode({ address: place }, function (results, status) {
```

...returns a `results` array, and you're accessing `results[0]`.

According to the [Google Maps developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro),

> Generally, only one entry in the "results" array is returned for address lookups, though the geocoder may return several results when address queries are ambiguous.

So, you may want to prompt the user if the `results` array contains more than one value.

EDIT: Since you've replied that you're only getting one value in the `results` array, you may want to check out this [Google blog post about address geocoding](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis), which states:

> The Geocoding API is best for handling unambiguous queries: complete postal address strings (for example, “48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont, NSW, Australia”).

You may want to use their [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?_ga=2.205564176.-202771619.1593447949):

> For applications that respond in real time to user input, we recommend using the Place Autocomplete service in the Places API. This service is designed to return multiple possible addresses and allow the user to choose between them.

Comment: ah so I just checked this but for some reason for `Split` it's still returning just 1 item? even though it's a city in Croatia

Comment: the 1 result being the california one

Comment: Hi Red Baron, did my updated response resolve the issue with the geocoding API? Is there anything else I can help with?